# Return response data from a web service using java

Tags: java, android

I am building an android application where I need to use a web service to POST data to it and return a string. To achieve this I have created an `AsyncTask` to do everything in background.

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            URL postUrl;
            try {
                postUrl = new URL("http://192.168.2.102/Rest%20Service/index.php");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid url");
            }

            String body = "mdxEmail=" + email + "&mdxPassword="+ password;

            byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
            String response = null;
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) postUrl.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                // post the request
                OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
                out.write(bytes);
                out.close();
                // handle the response
                int status = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (status != 200) {
                  throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
                } 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
```

My question is how can I get the data that is returned from the web service?

Comment: refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)..It will help you

Answer (score 0):

Once you posted you can get the returned data like this:

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason `inputLine` is returning null.